# PowerShell Rename-Item is creating a copy of the file

Tags: powershell, file-rename, windows-server-2016

My script is supposed to rename c:\myfolder\myfile.txt to myfile.bak

```
Rename-Item "c:\myfolder\myfile.txt" -NewName "myfile.bak"
```

However, it leaves myfile.txt in place and creates a new file called myfile.bak instead

Does anyone know why?

Comment: This should work. Can you try adding the -force parameter?

Comment: Hmm, force parameter worked. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Correction, force parameter didnt change anything - it was a Windows service that was running which was recreating the "missing" file after it had been renamed! Sorry for wasting everyones time.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I still added my comment as an answer since it may help someone else. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Good you figured it out but impov, you should close the question. This as it turns out has nothing to do with `Rename-Item` or Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a hidden or read-only file, you have to add the `-force` parameter:

> Forces the cmdlet to rename items that cannot otherwise be changed,
>   such as hidden or read-only files or read-only aliases or variables.
>   The cmdlet cannot change constant aliases or variables. Implementation
>   varies from provider to provider. For more information, see
>   about_Providers.

Comment: Martin, I'm gonna mark this as answered because its as close as one could get to fixing a similar problem. Option B would be to close the question :P

Comment: You can also close it, im fine with that :-). Cheers

Comment: Correction. You should add your solution as an answer and accept it. It might help someone.